Github pages не отображает последние изменения
работал над простеньким сайтом: https://github.com/VanoKi/new_portfolio
в локальном репо создал новую ветку, внес туда изменения, замерджил ветку с основной и запушил ее на удаленный репо
Вижу все изменения в файлах на гихаб, но... гитхаб пейджес не отображает изменения (должно появляться модальное окно по клику - не появляется, хотя в локальной версии все работает...)
Пробовал запускать сайт через режим инкогнито и на другом компе - проблема та же
в самом репо на гихаб все галочки коммитов - зеленые, конфликтов нет,
Пробовал переключить гитхабпейджес на другую ветку, ту, в которой разрабатывал модальное окно - все так же, изменения не применились, пробовал переключится обратно на маин, все то же...
скрин с гитхаб актинон - все зелененькое, никах ошибок не выводит...

А вот история коммитов:

а вот настройки деплоя:


Ничего не дает. И, как я уже упоминал, заходил в режиме инкогнито и совсем с другого компа - проблема та же. Изменения не применились

Если артефакт скачать, там будут ваши изменения? https://i.sstatic.net/2fxI5xWM.png

А как деплой у вас настроен?

Deploy from a branch
ветка main...

Для эксперимента добавьте пустой файл .nojekyll в корень (поправил, nojekyll должно быть)

"Если артефакт скачать, там будут ваши изменения? i.sstatic.net/2fxI5xWM.png " - да, изменения видны и все работает, так, как надо...

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.

Я открыл ваш сайт в инструментах разработчика, и там например в script.js есть те изменения, что вы сделали в последнем коммите. Я предполагаю, что это какая-то программная проблема, а не проблема github pages (либо какая-то особенность, связанная с тем, что сайт не локально запущен). Но тут уже мои компетенции заканчиваются, я ни разу не фронтендщик.

Спасибо, что пробовали разобраться в моей проблеме!
Мне по прежнему ничего не понятно, но теперь я хоть знаю, в каком направлении искать дальше...
